# Access Based Enumeration for Share Names or Disable All Share Broadcasting

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, server-message-block

Is there a way to apply Access Based Enumeration to Windows Server 2012 R2 SMB share names - so that unauthorized users can't see shares they don't have access to?

Or barring that is there a way (without appending $ to the share name) to make all shares non-broadcasted so that they can't be seen when browsing to \servername?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Is there a way to apply Access Based Enumeration to Windows Server 2012 R2 SMB share names - so that unauthorized users can't see shares they don't have access to?` - No. ABE works on the folders within the Share, not on the Share itself.

`Or barring that is there a way (without appending $ to the share name) to make all shares non-broadcasted so that they can't be seen when browsing to \servername?` - To clarify, Shares aren't "broadcasted". There's no mechanism to "hide" the share other than using $.

Comment: "ABE works on the folders within the share" - to clarify: Access-based enumeration also applies to files at the root directory of the share (not just folders).